# Why is this CSS3 transition glitchy?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, css-transitions

I'm having a glitchy CSS3 Transition.  I'm using the [filament responsive carousel](https://github.com/filamentgroup/responsive-carousel) and have some basic slides made up of an image, a title an `<hr>` and a subtitle.  What's happening is the OLD titles don't transition off the screen until after the NEW titles transition in.  It looks glitchy, and I can't seem to figure out why it's happening.

Now that I made the jsFiddle, I see the same thing is happening with my images, but on my site, the z-index changing is hiding the behavior behind the new image.  I think I would prefer no transition at all on the titles / images that are 'leaving'.

There's a lot of code, and the .js script changes it dynamically, so I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdBwM/).  You can see the glitchy behavior there.  The javascript applies styles to the transitioning slide that are indicated and relatively self-explanatory in the CSS, but head over to the Fiddle if you need more specificity.

The basic html looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel" data-transition="slide">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="myimage.gif" />
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        <hr />
        <h5>Subtitle 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="myimage2" />
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        <hr />
        <h5>Subtitle 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="myimage3" />
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        <hr />
        <h5>Subtitle 3</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.carousel-slide {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-slide .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* necessary for non-active slides */
    display: block; /* overrides basic carousel styles */
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: left .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: left .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: left .2s ease;
    -o-transition: left .2s ease;
    transition: left .2s ease;
}
.carousel-no-transition .carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
.carousel-slide .carousel-active {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.carousel-slide .carousel-in {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-slide-reverse .carousel-out {
    left: 100%;
}
.carousel-slide .carousel-out,
.carousel-slide-reverse .carousel-in {
    left: -100%;
}
.carousel-slide-reverse .carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition: left .1s ease;
    -moz-transition: left .1s ease;
    -ms-transition: left .1s ease;
    -o-transition: left .1s ease;
    transition: left .1s ease;
}
.carousel-slide-reverse .carousel-active {
    left: 0;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you should explore:

Firstly, [it can be more performant to transition transforms instead of box model properties](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) (eg. left, top, etc), eg:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
```

Then position them off the screen using using:

```
.carousel-item {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

or, if you prefer:

```
.carousel-item {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
```

The issue with the carousel item ghosting back across is because it is still being transitioned back to it's resting position when this should be instantaneous. You can do this by setting the transition timing to 0s, eg:

```
.carousel-item-instant {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

I see that you have a:

```
-webkit-transition: none;
```

class but this doesn't seem to be being applied correctly. You'll need to listen for the transition end event and then apply the

```
.carousel-item-instant
```

class to the appropriate carousel item. Note that you'll have to remove this again once it is time for the carousel item to animate again.

Comment: “it's bad practice to transition box model properties” — why?

Comment: Because transitioning box model properties can cause document reflow.

Comment: I ended up moving to a different slider (flexslider) that uses transition transforms.  The problem went away.  I think it was a combination of slow performance and the transition-out.  Marking as the answer - thanks!